# How to redirect URL containing question mark to different domain with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

It looks like this is a common issue since there are so many related questions here but I still have not found the solution after hours of searching...

I need to do many redirects via .htaccess for an old WordPress site. It uses URL's like this:

```
http://oldwpsite.com/?p=11
http://oldwpsite.com/?p=12
```

I need to redirect them something like this:

```
redirect 301 /?p=11 http://newwpsite.com/renting-a-scooter/  <--Does not work
redirect 301 /?p=12 http://newwpsite.com/scooter-tips/       <--Does not work
```

I have confirmed redirect does work with:

```
redirect 301 /xx.html http://newwpsite.com/  <--- Works
```

I tried many variations of RewriteEngine On, RewriteCond and RewriteRule but failed every time.

How can I do a redirect with question mark like the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should redirect the two pages to where you want them to go:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?p=11\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newwpsite.com/renting-a-scooter? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /\?p=12\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ http://newwpsite.com/scooter-tips? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: No problem, if it id help fix your problem, feel free to mark the answer as correct (the tick below the arrows to the left) so other people who might have the same problem you had will know how you solve it.